# 2 формы 1 submit (как реализовать)

Tags: forms, html, php, javascript

Всем привет!

Есть две формы, и отправку нужно осуществить одним сабмитом. Методы GET и POST. 
1 Форма - отправляет данные полей на емэйл.
2 Форма - переходит на сайт киви для оплаты. (Форма предоставлена сайтом)

Где то читал что onclick="document.getElementById('formid').submit()" но не срабатывает

Comment: Так что вам конкретно надо отправить значение на сервер или выполнить функцию?

Comment: Форма киви фо фрейме что ли?

Comment: Да. Html форма

Answer (score 1):

Например при помощи [jquery](http://jquery.com):

```
jQuery('form').submit(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'action',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: 1},
    })
})
```

Хотя по уму надо править функционал на сервере.

Comment: Можно по подробнее, я не профи в этом.

Comment: Если не профи - то нечего браться, особенно за системы оплаты.

Comment: Да как бы, я и не чайник. Просто этот сайт существует для вопросов и ответов. Вот и я спрашиваю

Comment: Наверное он говорит о том что нужно создать "один путь, ссылку, скрипт" который бы мог отправить и письмо и систему оплаты активировать. В целом у Вас подход на мой взгляд не совсем правильный к задаче.

Comment: Немного изменил вопрос!

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что речь идет о действиях по умолчанию. 
<input method="post" action="script.php">
Нужно добавить класс форме, повесить на этот класс событие onclick и в этом событии уже написать код, который будет активировать систему оплаты, и слать пост на сервер.
Плюс дефолтный хтмл-запрос нужно блокировать с помощью e.preventDefault()

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submit">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var target = getElementById('submit')

target.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {

        // Здесь вызываем js метод, который нам нужен,
        // А после делаем пост на обработчик формы.

        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
    }, false )
})
</script>
```

Comment: Немного изменил вопрос. 

Кстати вот через onClick пробывал не срабатывает. Не через класс, через айди. Вычитал где то на форумах такое.

Comment: Немного не пойму что делает этот скрипт?

Вот кнопка сабмита системы оплаты: <input type="submit" value="Выставить счёт за покупку" />

Шапка моей формы: <form name="lessonForm" id="lesform" method="POST" action="http://site.com/mail.php">

Кнопка моей формы которая отправляет email:  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="sub" value="Заказать">

Comment: Вот к форме оплаты как привязать действие кнопки от моей формы. 
В итоге: нажал на кнопку "Выставить счёт за покупку" действие перешли на сайт киви, и письмо отправилось с данными полей